# Getting length when flow length analysis only shows pixel value using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, length, flow

When I create a flow length analysis, and use identify tool on a cell in the layer, it just shows "stretched value" and "pixel value" I don't understand how it's supposed to show length.

I am using ArcMap.

Comment: Please expand a bit on what you're doing in a "flow length analysis." What command(s) created the "layer" you are inspecting?

Comment: The Flow Length tool is in Spatial Analyst/Hydrology. Once it is calculated, the output is nearly identical to Flow Accumulation Raster, but when you use the Identity tool on cells, it displays "Pixel Value", which is the distance (in pixels) that that line of flow travels (upstream or downstream depending on which you chose). Now I've noticed that the Flow Accumulation and Flow length rasters show that the cell size is 2.99 and if I divide a pixel value by that I get the approx. distance. I'd just like to display distance straight from the Identity tool without having to calculate it myself.

Comment: The help doc for the Flow Length tool states, "For each cell in the output raster, the result will be the number of cells that flow into it", which I'm assuming is a typo because that would be the case for flow accumulation. Regardless, it does indicate that you're right that the output value is in grid cells. If this is the case, then you need to multiply (not divide) the raster by the grid cell size to get the length in map units rather than grid cells. However, this only approximates the length, since the distance between diagonal neighbours is greater. I'm surprised they did it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Stretched value is the rendered value.  That is how it looks on the screen.  Pixel value is the real value that the pixel represents.  The latter is probably what most people are after.

Answer (score -1):

For ArcGIS Pro, the Flow Direction Raster input must be created as D8, not DINF type. Then the Flow Length will be the highest raster value in the same units as the original flow direction raster. If a DINF flow dir raster is provided, the flow length tool will not work properly, although it will create an erroneous output raster.

Comment: The question is about ArcMap.  It is fine to offer an answer that uses ArcGIS Pro but I think you need to make sure that you directly address the question and state how your ArcGIS Pro answer may be useful to an ArcMap user.

Comment: This question was asked 6 years ago. I found it while trouble shooting a similar issue, for which I shared the answer to my own issue. ArcMap has no option in the Flow Direction tool to use DINF so my answer only applies to ArcGIS Pro.